# How to config slick 3.2 connect to mysql by typesafe config package?

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I have attempted [official document for postgresql](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/database.html) and change `org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource` to `slick.driver.MySQLDriver$`

```
dataSourceClass = "slick.driver.MySQLDriver$"
properties = {
  databaseName = "mydb"
  user = "user"
  password = "password"
}
numThreads = 10
```

scala code:

```
val config = DatabaseConfig.forConfig[JdbcProfile]("slick.mysql.local")
```

Output error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing:  
No configuration setting found for key 'slick.mysql.local.profile'
```

Seems it need a `profile` property but what value should be added?

**============UPDATE========**
config properties are under brackets:

```
slick.mysql.local {
    dataSourceClass = "slick.driver.MySQLDriver$"
    properties = {
      databaseName = "mydb"
      user = "user"
      password = "password"
    }
    numThreads = 10
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you carefully read the docs, what they say is:

- define a `mydb` key in some `application.conf` with your configuration
- refer to that configuration using `val db = Database.forConfig("mydb")`

So I can only assume you're missing your `slick.mysql.local` key.

Comment: Hi, I change the root of slick config path. The full config see UPDATE in question, thanks. Besides,there are some another doubting, the config not point mysql host and port.Is it will work?

Comment: Try adding a  `url` key just after `dataSourceClass` with something like `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?user=root&password=password`.

Answer (score 1):

I also found it difficult to configure the database connector. Here is my config:

```
mysql {
  dataSourceClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"
  properties = {
    url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dbName"
    databaseName = "dbName"  <= maybe not necessaray as also in the url
    user = "root"
    password = ""
  }
  numThreads = 10
}
```

Thanks to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalaquery/WbR6yHzBj_8

Answer (score 0):

I struggle some days and find a config can works.

```
  driver = "slick.driver.MySQLDriver$"
  db {
    url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/develop_tdsystem?user=user&password=password"
    driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    maxThreads = 10
  }
```

please notice there are some warning:

```
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
[warn] c.z.h.u.DriverDataSource - Registered driver with driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
```